# Synchronized block with private immutable object and synchronize method difference

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

```
private final Object lockObject = new Object();
public void getCount() {
    synchronized( lockObject ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Why above code is better than below one:

```
public void synchronized getCount() {
      ...
}
```

I searched and found explanation as mentioned below.

> Putting it on the method means you are using the lock of the object
>   itself to provide thread safety. With this kind of mechanism, it is
>   possible for a malicious user of your code to also obtain the lock on
>   your object, and hold it forever, effectively blocking other threads.
>   A non-malicious user can effectively do the same thing inadvertently.

But i couldn't understand this completely. How a mallicious user can hold a lock for ever? Can any one give an explanation with a sample code, to justify above scenario?

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20907514/4405757

Comment: @user7 Iam not looking for difference between synchronized block and synchronized method. .

Comment: I guess it is already mentioned in that answer pretty well

Comment: Just curious: why do you want to know the differences here?  Are you having some problems?  General question on best practice?  Something else?

Comment: A malicious user can hold the lock forever like this: `synchronized (yourObject) { while (true); }`.

Comment: You can look at it from the positive side: when you lock on a **private** object, no one can (lets say easily) obtain lock on the same object. It prevents unexpected locks.

Comment: @markspace Just curious to know about the difference. While reading a java `synchronization` article i came across such  a practice but i couldn't understand it completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
public class Example {
    public void synchronized getCount() {
            ...
    }
}
```

it's synchronizing on current object `this`. Other class is able to get the reference of current object and use it as monitor lock:

```
public class OtherClass {

    public void otherMethod() {
        Example example = new Example();
        synchronized (example) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This might get unexpected results, for example, causing `getCount` blocked when `otherMethod` being executed.

With the first approach, since the monitor lock `lockObject` is private, other class is not able to access it directly, so it's preferred over the second approach.

Answer (score 0):

To put in simple words  -

When you use locking at method level you are getting lock of object of complete class in which you have synchronised method.

Suppose if any user comes with some shiny code to execute method till universe ends .. this will result in other threads getting blocked for using other methods in your class.

This is a reason monitor objects and synchronised blocks are preferred way.