# Java delay return value

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a situation where I read data from a YAML file that is important for the application because it is used in several classes. Here is my code:

```
public class CredentialsReader {
    private UserCredentials credentials;
    private boolean isReading = false;


    public CredentialsReader() {
    }

    public void readCredentials() {
        Runnable readerTask = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                isReading = true;
                parseCredentials();
                isReading = false;
                System.err.println("Parsed credentials");
            }
        };
        ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        service.scheduleAtFixedRate(readerTask, 0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

    private void parseCredentials() {
        final File f = new File("/home/dev/IdeaProjects/server/src/main/resources/credentials.yaml");
        try {
            UserCredentials userCredentials = new ObjectMapper().readValue(f, UserCredentials.class);
            this.credentials = userCredentials;
            System.out.println(this.credentials.getUsername() + ", " + this.credentials.getPassword());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }  
    public UserCredentials getCredentials() { return this.credentials; }


}
```

As you see, I read the data every minute and my question is:
Can I delay the return value of getCredentials, so when the method is called I check if `isReading` is `true` and then delay the return so I can guarantee that a caller will always get the actual state of the yaml file?

Comment: I think the a clean way to do this is by using the [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) interface.

Comment: If you're reading the file every minute and `parseCredentials()` takes a handful of milliseconds, is it really going to make any noticeable difference to the user?

Answer (score 3):

I think there are appropriate locks for similar situations, but this seems like synchronize is sufficient.

```
synchronized private void parseCredentials() {...}
synchronized public UserCredentials getCredentials() { ... }
```

By declaring those methods synchronized only one thread at a time will be able to enter the method, essentially a barrier. That means that parseCredentials could have to wait for getCredentials, but getCredentials is so trivially fast you'll never notice.

That will synchronize on an instance of CredentialReader, so if you use more than one, you might want to synchronize on something else. As mentioned it the comments it is better to synchronize on a private object rather than the instance itself. It is a small change:

```
public class CredentialsReader {
    private UserCredentials credentials;
    private boolean isReading = false;
    final private Object lock = new Object();
    ...
```

Then remove the synchronize from the method signature and add a synchronize call in the body.

```
private void parseCredentials() {
     synchronize(lock){
         //original code goes here.
     }
}
```

Also, `isReading` should be volatile.

Comment: In general, don't use synchronized method modifier. It's better to synchronize on a private object - else some other code might (maybe unintentionally) synchronize on your CredentialsReader instance and block your code. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906548/why-is-synchronized-block-better-than-synchronized-method (also read the comments of the accepted answer and the other answers).

Answer (score 2):

I do not suggest to do it manually, you could use a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) with init value `1` provided in jdk.

You can let the readers calls [`await`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#await()), and let the writer calls [`countDown`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#countDown()) once data is prepared.

So the reader could always get fully initialized data.